# Fileupload is not working in Microsoft IE and Microsoft Edge Browser in ASP.NET WebForm

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, webforms, web-controls

> I have a code in VB.NET just to upload a file in ASP.NET WebForm. It is working perfectly in Firefox, Chrome and Safari. But the same code is unable to save the uploaded file in Microsoft Internet Explorer and Microsoft Edge, although there is no any error or exception in the application. I need someone's help to fix the issue. My .aspx code and code-behind file's code are as below:

**WebForm1.ASPX**

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.vb" Inherits="FileUploadTest.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:FileUpload ID="Uploader" runat="server" />
            <asp:Button ID="cmdUpload" runat="server" Text="Upload"  />
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**CodeBehind File**

```
Imports System.IO

Public Class WebForm1
    Inherits Page

    Dim uploadDirectory As String = "C:\Uploads\"
    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    End Sub

    Protected Sub cmdUpload_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdUpload.Click
        Dim uniqueGuid As String = Guid.NewGuid.ToString

        Dim tmpUploadDirectory As String = uploadDirectory & "\" & uniqueGuid

        If Not Directory.Exists(tmpUploadDirectory) Then
            Directory.CreateDirectory(tmpUploadDirectory)
        End If

        For Each f As HttpPostedFile In Uploader.PostedFiles
            f.SaveAs(Path.Combine(tmpUploadDirectory, f.FileName))
        Next
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It was mainly because Internet Explorer and Microsoft Edge give full file path while in Chrome, Firefox and Safari just give the only file name. I have attached the screenshots below and by using Path.GetFileName method I only get file names, no matter what it gives filename only or fullpath.

The first image is while uploading file from Internet Explorer and Microsoft Edge and the second one is from Chrome, Firefox and Safari

[image]

[image]

We can also explicitly enable/disable file name only or full path in the browser setting as well. For instance, below I have attached a screenshot from Internet Explorer where we can Enable or Disable "Include local directory path when uploading files to a server".

[image]

Comment: Hi This setting is not working for Edge browser for me

Comment: @RahulTokase This option is not working for me in Edge but in my case, Path.GetFileName(...) worked fine to get the filename irrespective of a full path or just filename.

Comment: On IE 10 OK. Thank you.